# Sum of two projection Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

*E1* and *E2* are two projections onto two independent subspace. Then, is *E1* + *E2* projection ?

Comment: Notice that identity map $id$ is a projection whats $id+id$?

Comment: @user52045 if $E1=id$ then what is $E2$ if you require independent (sub)spaces?

Comment: Sorry i didnt notice that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Is $E_1+E_2=(E_1+E_2)\circ(E_1+E_2)$?